# API permission check failed: CiviEvents Fails after update to 4.7.19 and 4.7.20

Tags: civievent, api, permissions

After updating to 4.7.20, when the Event Info Page is accessed, it generates the following error, "API permission check failed for Event/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM and access CiviEvent and view event info". If I roll the system back to 4.7.18 it works. Any suggestions on a fix or work-around are much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm - if you had said this only for 4.7.19 i would have said https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10325 was the fix. but that is in 4.7.20 afaik - can  you check the 4.7.20 code you had and confirm if that fix was in there. that said, may be entirely unrelated. just been applying this to a number of 4.7.19 sites hence on top of my mind

Comment: this was related jira - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20549

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't resolve the issue. I compared the file with the one on githubusercontent.com, but couldn't see any changes, so I replaced my event.php with the one there. No change, still getting the "API permission check failed for Event/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM and access CiviEvent and view event info" error message.

Comment: After updating to 4.7.22, I'm still receiving the following error: "API permission check failed for Event/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM and access CiviEvent and view event info"  when I try to access Event Info. Any suggestion for a fix/work-around would be appreciated. Currently, the only option I have is to roll back to civiCRM 4.7.18.

Comment: It may not be a valid work-a-around, but I've discovered a way to run 4.7.22 without getting the API permission error when trying to view Event Info from the front-end. I changed the ACL, 'CiviCRM: access CiviCRM' permissions for 'Public' users from the default, 'Inherited' to 'Allowed'.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same issue which occurred on my Drupal install after upgrading, and it blocks all event access from users not logged in. I was on 4.7, and just updated to 5.7.2 hoping it would fix it. No luck. I have no such ACL to fix this. I'm panicking as we need to get an event live and have never had this issue before and I'd rather not downgrade to 4.7.18.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in to this on an inherited site. It fixed itself once I removed the permission for "access CiviEvent" (which i assume had been erroneously given by previous developers)

Once removed the other permissions worked fine.

Maybe this counts as a bug. Will raise up a level.

Comment: This worked for me too on Drupal. Specifically, in the CMS permission "CiviEvent: Access CiviEvent" for anonymous users.

Comment: Thx Harold. StackExchange works best if you Up vote tickets that are useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed this bug and reported at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1517

PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16266 should fix the problem.