# After upgrade to 5.0.1 - anonymous users can't see any events

Tags: civievent, permissions

The upgrade, in Drupal 7.58, was done some months ago. We have an annual event so I'm only noticing this after trying to set up the new event, but anonymous users can no longer view any events. The error is the following:

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
API permission check failed for Event/get call; insufficient permission: require access CiviCRM and access CiviEvent and view event info

There were no changes to permissions, and this worked before. I double checked, and the anonymous access via CiviEvent is still on.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured this out, but it still looks like a bug (sorry I won't probably won't be able to confirm right away and submit a JIRA issues). The Drupal "CiviEvent: Access CiviEvent" seems to need anonymous turned off or anonymous can't view. I had this set because I thought it was necessary, but it isn't for anonymous to view specific events, I think it means to view a listing of events. This still seems like a bug, but I'm glad it's at least working again.

This may also have been the cause for the [API permission check failed: CiviEvents Fails after update to 4.7.19 and 4.7.20](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19038)

Comment: Just a not that JIRA is now a relic and you need to head to https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues